# Flutter: How to AUTO RESIZE height, width, fontSize in ListView based on Expanded and itemCount

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have a page like this:

1. 1st Listview: `Axis.vertical` as default
2. 2nd Listview inside 1st Listview: `Axis.horizontal`, `itemCount = 3`. To avoid the error, I set the `height:50` `width:100` for `Container` in this

However, I want to find some way for it to display well on all screens, specifically in the 2nd ListView:

- **`Expanded` (1: 1: 1) and it fits the right of the screen, can't scroll.**
- **`Width` of `Container` will auto-resize based on `Expanded flex`.**
- **`fontSize` of `Text` and `Height` of `Container` will auto-resize based on `maxLine`**

[image]

So pls help me, this is JSON file

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "continent": "North America",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "United States",
        "capital": "Washington, D.C.",
        "language": ["English"]
      },
      {
        "country": "Canada",
        "capital": "Ottawa",
        "language": ["English", "French"]
      },
      {
        "country": "Mexico",
        "capital": "Mexico City",
        "language": ["Spanish"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "continent": "Europe",
    "countries": [
      {
        "country":  "Germany",
        "capital": "Berlin",
        "language":  ["German"]
      },
      {
        "country":  "United Kingdom",
        "capital": "London",
        "language":  ["English"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": [
      {
        "country":  "Singapore",
        "capital": "Singapore",
        "language":  ["English","Malay","Mandarin","Tamil"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this is the main file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'model/continent_model.dart';
import 'services/continent_services.dart';

class ContinentPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  ContinentPage2() : super();

  @override
  _ContinentPageState createState() => _ContinentPageState();
}

class _ContinentPageState extends State<ContinentPage2> {
  List<Continent> _continent;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ContinentServices.getContinent().then((continents) {
      setState(() {
        _continent = continents;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('')),
        body: ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 10);
            },
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: null == _continent ? 0 : _continent.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text(_continent[index].continent)),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          child: ListView.separated(
                              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return SizedBox(width: 10);
                              },
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: null == _continent ? 0 : _continent[index].country.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, countryIndex) {
                                print(_continent[index].country[countryIndex].name);
                                return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          _continent[index].country[countryIndex].name,
                                        ),
                                        Text(_continent[index].country[countryIndex].capital,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.blue,
                                            )),
                                      ]))
                                ]);
                              })))
                ])
              ]);
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: You are asking a lot of things. I'll try to help you on how to achieve those things. You can use a package called auto_size_text to automatically resize your text based on the amount of space remaining. Also, Why do you want to use listviews when you can use rows and columns in the first place. For your second expanded, place it inside your first expanded's flex 2. Use a Row then inside of it, place your first expanded. Place a column in each of your first expanded items. Add a row for each item you want to display in the first expanded item. Set the row's mainaxisalignment to add spacing.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `AutoTextSize` :D, my first version did exactly as you said ^^, there will have to be 3 `Container` to show 3 specific "country". However, this JSON file has countries in List Array, so as far as I know, I think it will need to use the 2nd `ListView` and only 1 `Container`,  is that true?

Comment: you can also use a ListView if you want. Just don't forget to wrap it inside a Widget with a predefined height and width so that your listview won't take infinite space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:math'; //useful to check the longest list of countries 

class ContinentPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  ContinentPage2() : super();

  @override
  _ContinentPageState createState() => _ContinentPageState();
}

class _ContinentPageState extends State<ContinentPage2> {
  List<Continent> _continent = []; //initialize empty to avoid problem with the table
  int maxLength; //we need to check for the longest list of countries in all the continents

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ContinentServices.getContinent().then((continents) {
      setState(() {
        _continent = continents;
        maxLength = _continent.map((continent) => continent.country.length).reduce(max); 
        /*max uses dart:math, I made a list of the length of all the List<countries>
        and then check for the list with the maximum length*/
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Table(
          defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
          columnWidths: {0: FlexColumnWidth(0.5)}, //accept a map and gives to the index the width I want, in this case the first widget a flex of 0.5, and the others will have the default 1, so it's the same as using expanded with flex: 1 and then flex: 2
          children: [
            for (Continent continent in _continent)
              TableRow(children: [
                TableCell(
                  verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  child: Text(continent.continent),
                ),
                for (Country country in continent.country)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              child: Text(country.name),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                child: Text(
                                  country.capital,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )),
                          ),
                          //OPTION 1 create a String with all the languages as a single text
                          if(country.languages.isNotempty)
                          Flexible(
                            child: MyLanguages(
                                lang: country.languages.reduce((prev, curr) => '$prev, $curr')
                            )
                          ),
                          // Option 2 using a for to create multiple text widgets inside the column widget with all the languages per country
                          if(country.languages.isNotempty)
                          for(String language in country.language)
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text(language)
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
                if (continent.country.length < maxLength)
                  for (int i = 0; i < maxLength - continent.country.length; i++)
                    const SizedBox()
              ])
          ],
        )));
  }
}


// Used in Option 1
class MyLanguages extends StatelessWidget{
  final String languages;

  MyLanguages({String lang, Key key}) : languages = lang.replaceFirst(',', ' and', lang.lastIndexOf(',').clamp(0, double.infinity)), super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text(languages);
  }


}
```

With all the nested Rows and Columns I thought the best idea was tu use a Table widget, it allows to make a table of x rows with y columns, but there is only one problem, all the rows need to have the same amount of columns (rectangular or square table). So to work around that I made an int maxLength, then:

```
maxLength = _continent.map((continent) => continent.country.length).reduce(max);
```

Makes a List with all the lengths of the countries and with reduce max I retrieve the value of the the list with the maximum length, useful for the next part

```
if (continent.country.length < maxLength)
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength - continent.country.length; i++)
   const SizedBox()
```

Here I check if I made a full row or if that row has less widgets that the maximum I will have in any row, and then just add dummys const SizedBox() to trick the Table that it has the same amount of widgets in every Row (if you comment this part it will give you an error because it needs to have the same amount of columns).

```
columnWidths: {0: FlexColumnWidth(0.5)},
```

This line works as flex with Expanded, it accepts a map Map where the key int is the index of the column in each row, in this case 0 and I give it a flex 0.5, and the others keep the default 1.0. There are other [TableColumnWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TableColumnWidth-class.html) classes if you want to give it a try

Finally I wrapped the Countries in a Padding with vertical 5 to make it look like your separatorbuilder SizedBox(height: 10), inside the Columns I wrapped the text with a Flexible and FittedBox with fit.scaleDown so it reduce the size of the text in case it fills all the width and added the textAlign.center to center the text. In case you have a big large text it will reduce it's size to fill. If you don't want that you can keep only the Text widget and add maxLines and softWrap

```
Text(
  country.capital,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  maxLines: 2, softWrap: true,
)
```

Or you could check the [Auto_Size_Text Package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) if you really want more customization with the size of the text

Result with fittedBox

[image: With FittedBox]

Result without FittedBox and maxLines: 2, softwrap: true

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm! And I am also overwhelmed by this new knowledge :P. I would probably spend all day researching it, Thank you for the meticulousness of your answer xD

Comment: Until now I almost understand your code, it's incredible!. However, in case I have added a List <String> in `country` (Ex "language"), how can I show it [img](https://i.imgur.com/br6h4pj.jpg)? I have updated the JSON file on the post. Please help me

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 options, check each one and use / adapt to your needs whichever you prefer

Comment: Ahhh, I figured it out [img](https://i.imgur.com/ZM6RVcP.jpg) hah, thanks to you anyway.

Comment: Ops, I have just read your latest comment, this answer update is perfect for what I need. Many thanks, xD

Comment: Pls give me another favor, in case I want the `Text(language)` to display in Row like [this](https://i.imgur.com/wTkLAj2.jpg), how do I do it? I tried wrapping it in `Row` but it didn't work _(I chose option 2 from your latest answer)_

Comment: Edit 2: If possible, add a separator with "|" like [this](https://i.imgur.com/4LzWSkk.png), it would be awesome

Comment: Text(country.languages.reduce((prev, curr) => '$prev | $curr'))